# Get shipping price with and without taxes

Tags: magento2, quote, programmatically, address, shipping-tax

I doing a connection with a webmarketplace.

So I developed a script to export my products into a xml file. But, one of the problems I have is that I can't get the shipping amount.

I need to get the shipping price with and without taxes but anyway, firstly I just experiment the magento2 code to get the shippingAmount by country and shippingMethod.

I use the table rate shipping method, and I show you the CSV file of my table rate.

My question is, can I get the shipping amount (with and without taxes) with this kind of method. Because it return every time "null".

This, is my script code to get shipping amount

```
    $quoteFactory = $this->objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
    $quote = $quoteFactory->create();
    $quote->setStore($this->currentStore);
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);

    $shipModel = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping');
    $quote->addProduct($product, 1);
    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $address->setCountryId('US')
        ->setCity('')
        ->setPostcode('*')
        ->setRegionId('')
        ->setRegion('')
        ->setShippingMethod(current($carriers))
        ->setCollectShippingrates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates();

    $quote->save();

    die(json_encode($address->getShippingAmount())); //debug
```

And now, my table rate csv file.

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"

USA, * ,*,0.0000,15.0000

USA, * ,*,50.0000,10.0000

USA, * ,*,100.0000,5.0000

USA,AK,*,0.0000,20.0000

USA,AK,*,50.0000,15.0000

USA,AK,*,100.0000,10.0000


USA,HI,*,0.0000,20.0000

USA,HI,*,50.0000,15.0000

USA,HI,*,100.0000,10.0000
```

Thanks.

EDIT (About product and carrier)

```
$carriers = array('tablerate');

$store = $this->storeManager->getStore($store_id);

$products = $this->productCollection
                            ->addStoreFilter($store)
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->load()

foreach ($products as $product) {

    $product->setStoreId($store->getId())->load($product->getId());


    // AND HERE THE CODE ABOVE


}
```

Comment: Please add more detail about `$carriers` and `$product` object

Comment: I added information about $carriers and $product objet